# Generic set state function for different objects within React

Tags: reactjs

I have a pretty basic component that contains 2 objects within the state.

```
export default class MainForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            time_frame: {},
            event_view: {},
       }
   }
}
```

Each of these objects contains a value name and true if my user clicks a certain checkbox, so it builds up a list of values like

```
"event_view": {"app":true, "web":true}
```

To handle the change, I create a copy of each object and then fill in the values that a user chooses, I'm wondering if there's a generic way to do this in React? Rather than having to check the `event.target.name` value

My way doesn't seem very efficient.

```
handleRadioChange(event) {
    let name = event.target.name
    let timeFrameCopy = {...this.state.time_frame};
    let eventViewCopy = {...this.state.event_view};

    if (name === "time_frame") {
        timeFrameCopy[event.target.value] = true
        this.setState({
            [name]: timeFrameCopy,
        }, this.checkState)
        return
    }

    if (name === "event_view") {
        eventViewCopy[event.target.value] = true
        this.setState({
            [name]: eventViewCopy,
        }, this.checkState)
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, to also save your previous state

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  [name]: value
}))
```